# why the angular elements are undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have some view:

```html
<h1>Сотрудники</h1>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Добавить" (click)="add()"/>
<table *ngIf="tableMode;" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Пол</td>
    <td>Отдел</td>
    <td>Язык программирования</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngIf="employee">
  <tr *ngFor="let e of employees$ | async; trackBy: trackByEmpID">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="employee?.employeeID != e.employeeID" [ngIfElse]="edit">
      <td>{{e.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{e.department.name}}</td>
      <td>{{e.language.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="editEmployee(e)">Изменить</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="delete(e)">Удалить</button>
      </td>
    </ng-template>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div *ngIf="!tableMode" [style.display]="'none'">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Пол</label>
    <label>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.gender">
        <option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender?.value">
          {{gender?.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Отдел</label>
  <label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.department.name">
      <option *ngFor="let d of empDepartments$ | async" [value]="d?.name">
        {{d?.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Язык программирования</label>
  <label>
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.language.name">
      <option *ngFor="let l of empLanguages$ | async" [value]="l?.name">
        {{l?.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Сохранить" (click)="submit()" class="btn btn-success"/>
    <input type="button" value="Отмена" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-warning"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and some TypeScript code behind:

```js
interface Gender {
  name: string,
  value: boolean
}

@Component({
  selector: 'emps',
  templateUrl: 'emps.component.html',
  providers: [employeeService, departmentsService, languagesService]

})

export class empsComponent implements OnInit{
  employee: Employee = new Employee();
  employees$: Observable<Object>;
  empDepartments$: BehaviorSubject<Department[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Department[]>(null);
  empLanguages$: BehaviorSubject<Language[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Language[]>(null);
  tableMode: boolean = true;
  genders: Gender[] = [{name: "Муж", value: true}, {name: "Жен",value:false}];

  constructor(private employeeService: employeeService,
              private languagesService: languagesService,
              private departmentsService: departmentsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.genders);
    this.loadAllData();
  }

  loadAllData(){
    this.employees$ = this.employeeService.getEmployees()
      .pipe(tap(()=>
      {
        this.departmentsService.getDepartments().subscribe((data:Department[])=>this.empDepartments$.next(data));
        console.log(this.empDepartments$);
        this.languagesService.getLanguages().subscribe((data:Language[])=>this.empLanguages$.next(data));
        console.log(this.empLanguages$);
      }))
  }
```

so, as you can see, the employees$, empDepartments$, empLanguages$, and Genders[] are all initialized and set collections [proof1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TMWH.png), [proof2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3M0s.png), and [proof3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzKXr.png). But when i'm trying to *ngFor over them in the div down on the HTML they are all [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNwso.png). How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first I don't really know where the error is coming from, but my guess is not within `*ngFor` but within your `[(ngModel)]`.

You define in your `component.ts`

```
employee: Employee = new Employee(); // Does this have anything in it predefined?
// you're not changing this anywhere in your code
```

And in your HTML

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.department.name"> // is this defined?
    <option *ngFor="let d of empDepartments$ | async" [value]="d?.name">
        {{d?.name}}
    </option>
</select>
...
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="employee.language.name"> // what about this?
    <option *ngFor="let l of empLanguages$ | async" [value]="l?.name">
        {{l?.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm changing it on Edit (StackOverflow says that there is too much code in my question, that's why it's not posted here, and i mean to POST on server what is collected from forms to create a new Employee object)

Comment: according to your answer, i just used an Elvis operator (?.) and it worked. Thanks so much bro